# Populate large class from fixed width data

Tags: c#

I have a class with a large number of properties, example:

```
class MyStudent {
    public string NAME;
    public string TUTOR;
    public int AGE;
    // ... 100+ items
}
```

The data is read from a fixed width text file:

```
Matt    John    20
JonathonBob     22
```

The data file is defined in a separate xref file:

```
NAME    8
TUTOR   8
AGE     2
```

I want to populate my class from each line of data then add it to a list of this type.  This is the method I am using, can it be made more efficient (without changing the input data files)?

Firstly I've read the xref file into a list so I can access the WIDTH field using LINQ.

```
/* Read File */
List<MyStudent> signal_file = new List<MyStudent>();
while ((_dba_line = _dba_file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (!_dba_line.Substring(0, 2).Equals("--")) // Not a comment
    {
        MyStudent temp_signal = new MyStudent();
        int _offset = 0;
        int _width = 0;

        _width = xref_file.First(item => item.DBU_FIELD == "NAME").WIDTH;
        temp_signal.NAME = _dba_line.Substring(_offset, _width).Trim();
        _offset += _width;

        _width = xref_file.First(item => item.DBU_FIELD == "TUTOR").WIDTH;
        temp_signal.TUTOR = _dba_line.Substring(_offset, _width).Trim();
        _offset += _width;

        // Continue for each property
        // ...

        // Finally
        signal_file.Add(temp_signal);
    }
}
```

I think the key may be that the xref DBU_FIELD always equals the property name in the class and is in the correct order to match the line of data.  What I would like to achieve if possible would be closer to:

```
foreach (XrefObject x in xref_file)
{
    _width = x.WIDTH;
    temp_signal.(x.DBU_FIELD) = _dba_line.Substring(_offset, _width).Trim();
    _offset += _width;
}

// Finally
signal_file.Add(temp_signal);
```

It's how to use the xref object DBU_FIELD value to access the student object associated property I am unsure of (if possible).

For info in this use the files have been validated prior to use so they are guaranteed to match up correctly.

I am open to create as a struct rather than an object if that makes more sense, there are typically 500 instances each with approx 100 fields of mixed string, int and float.

I am also looking for the best practice way to handle this type of data structure, not just force it to work.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Is this under your influence? Is there a database system involved? Is the type of your data sepcified in your xref-file (e.g. `AGE   2   INT`)?

Comment: If it's fixed width wouldn't it be better to just work on the stream and use offset to read through it without 'readline' and all those substrings? That way you minimize the number of string operations.

Comment: The data is the format used in a proprietary application of ours, it can't be changed and I want to use the same source data that goes into the application rather than attempt to extract separately from the database/spreadsheets that create it.  The xref file does provide the type but it isn't a perfect match for C#.  I'm happy to manually handle the configuration of the xref object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx)'s  `GetProperty` and `SetValue` methods

```
using System.Reflection;        

foreach (XrefObject x in xref_file)
{
    _width = x.WIDTH;

    PropertyInfo prop = 
        temp_signal.GetType()
            .GetProperty(x.DBU_FIELD, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    if(prop != null && prop.CanWrite)
    {
        prop.SetValue(temp_signal, _dba_line.Substring(_offset, _width).Trim(), null);
    }

    _offset += _width;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked well, as I have a mixture of data types I had to add the following: `if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(float)) { prop.SetValue(temp_signal, float.Parse(_dba_line...), null); }` for each type required

Comment: For others benefit doing this you must check the length of the sub-string too if a field may be empty, trying to Parse an empty string to a numeric type throws an exception.